# Grabbing GPS Location iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, gps, location

I am trying to grab the location of the iPhone's current location and I am not sure what I am doing wrong, nothing logs or appears....

Code is here:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
  int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
  int minutes = decimal * 60;
  double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
           degrees, minutes, seconds];
  statusText.text = lat;
  degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
  decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
  minutes = decimal * 60;
  seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
  NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
             degrees, minutes, seconds];
  statusText.text = longt;


}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [statusText.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\":" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\":" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\":" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\":" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    return center;
}



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

In order: Grabbing the long and lat, Converting it with Google Map API and calling the locationManager first of all when the app launches.

The coordinates appear just simply converting them to an actual location does not happen

Answer (score 0):

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
             fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

This delegate will not work on some iOS SDK's. Have you test it in device and checked.

Comment: that delegate works fine, it grabs the coordinates with the simulator working perfectly, but in order to covert it into an address do I need to test on my device still for the other delegate to work?

Comment: I tested it on the device. Simply this is what happens. That delegate works fine, its grabs the coordinates however I want those coordinates that it grabs in the statusText.text to transfer into a location

Answer (score 0):

There's a class in MapKit called MKReverseGeocoder. You initialize it with the coordinate of the location you received and start it up. It will return a MKPlacemark from its delegate. Use MKPlacemark to access things like address, city, state, postal code, country etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also grab a free zipcode database in for US and some others, (which includes lat/longitudes) then test for nearest. Then there's no reliance on API's.